# How to redirect previous page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How to redirect previous page after redirect to previous page.
After form submission i am redirect form to thank you page but after sometimes i want redirect previous page.

Below is the code i am using

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    //location = 'abc.com1/thank-you/';
     if ( '17615' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
     } 
    else if( '19110' == event.detail.contactFormId ){
        location = 'abc.com1/thank-you-broucher/';
    }
    else {
         location = 'abc.com1/thank-you/';
     }
}, false );
</script>
```

after location redirect i want again redirect to my first original page.

Anyone have idea then let me know

Comment: ``` switch (event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
     case '17615' : break;
     case '19110': {
        location = 'abc.com1/thank-you-broucher/'; break;
    }
    default:{
         location = 'abc.com1/thank-you/'; break;
     }

```

Comment: window.location.history(-1) is how you go back

Comment: Manually redirecting the user to a page they've already been to is a code smell. It can lead to issues with caching, especially if forms are involved. I'd suggest you change the UI flow so that the user cannot progress until all business logic requirements have been met - assuming this is required for validation reasons.

Answer (score 2):

use [history.back](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back)

```js
window.history.back();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it several ways:

```
// Javascript directly in the href    
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>
```

another way would be:

```
// onclick Method
<a href="#" onClick="history.go(-1); return false;">Go back</a>
```

Or as mentioned above my post

```
// windows method
javascript:window.history.back();
```

and for last you can create a function

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    history.go(-1);
}
</script>
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

If you want to have it done automatically you just need to use it in a function and add a setTimeout:

```
function goBackTimed() {  
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.history.go(-1);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Since your using WordPress, I would recommend doing this using the functions.php file and add a filter with a function for the redirect, but since you requested how to do this with javascript, you need to inspect your thank you page to grab the page-id-[ID-NUMBER] class it generates on the body tag your script above would need a condition to detect if the class is present on the body assuming this script is loaded on your entire site:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    //location = 'abc.com1/thank-you/';
     if ( '17615' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
     } 
    else if( '19110' == event.detail.contactFormId ){
        location = 'abc.com1/thank-you-broucher/';
    }
    else {
         location = 'abc.com1/thank-you/';
     }
}, false );

if (document.body.classList.contains('page-id-12345')) {

   function goBack() {
        history.go(-1);
    }
    window.setInterval(goBack, 3000);
}
</script>
```

I prefer history.go(); since you can go back even more than 1 page back for example history.go(-2); would go back 2 pages instead of one, this sometimes can be handy in certain cases.

Comment: But how to add in my code after 3 seconds send to original previous page? I want automatically send to previous page

Comment: I added a function to send you back automatically now, let me know if you need more help, you can use that last function either with clicks or windows loads etc...

Comment: if ( '17615' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends sumissions on form 17615 to the first thank you page
  } 
 else if( '19110' == event.detail.contactFormId ){
  location = 'abc.com11/thank-you-broucher/';
  goBackTimed();
 }
 else {
   location = 'abc.com11/thank-you/';
   goBackTimed();
  }
}, false );
function goBackTimed() {  
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.history.go(-1);
  }, 3000);
}-

Comment: i tried above but its not working anything wrong in that?

Comment: Are you placing the function on your form page, this would need to be on the thank you page.

Comment: also since I notice this is for wordpress why not add a function in your function.php that would be easy  I will also add an example of that above in a few

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem with using `js` built in `history.go(-1);` is that the behaviour is based on your browser and not on your website structure.

If someone decide to access a website straight from a url or a bookmark, upon using `history.go(-1);` on landing, he would be redirected outside the website environment.

---

### As you're using Wordpress

We can easily build a go back url function based on the current user url.

Anything that can be offloaded to server should be. Instead of using `js` here is a `php` alternative. The main advantage here is quartering the user to your website. Here is our `get_backward_url()` function.

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_backward_url' );
function get_backward_url() {

    $scheme = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
    $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    if ( str_contains( $request, '?' ) ) { //... case handling, urls with variables
        $cleaner = substr( $request, 0, strpos( $request, '?' ) );
        $request = $cleaner;
    };
        
    if ( str_ends_with( $request, '/' ) ) //... case handling, urls with/without end-slash
        $worker = explode( '/', substr( $request, 1, -1 ) );
    else
        $worker = explode( '/', substr( $request, 1 ) );
        
    array_pop( $worker );
    
    if ( str_contains( $host, 'localhost' ) ) //... case handling, urls on local hosting
        $href = esc_url( $scheme . '://' . $host . '/' . implode( '/', $worker ) . '/' );
    else
        $href = esc_url( $scheme . '://' . $host . implode( '/', $worker ) . '/' );

    if ( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) //... case handling, home or front page
        return $href;

};
```

Then, anytime we need to use it in our template we can simply output it on the front end...

```
<a href="<?= get_backward_url(); ?>">← go back</a>
```

[Happy coding!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u6GS4wmVNk)